# Automatically change image-url by 1 for next div?

Tags: css

I'm making a bunch of stacked divs that will expand when moused-over to show an image, but I have a lot of images.
Is there a way in CSS or JS (I don't really know anything about JS) to have each div automatically use the next image in a folder? ex: the images are named **map1.jpg**, **map2.jpg** ... **map91.jpg**. and be able to use the same `background-image:url` but have something telling it to add 1 to the next image for each new div so I don't have to manually specify 90+ different images.

I hope I was able to explain that well enough.  Thanks =)

Comment: please add to your explanation the things you tried by yourself

Answer (score 1):

In CSS this is impossible, cause you can't concatenate the url path for background-image.

in javascript this is pretty simple, using jQuery you can simply load all div you need when body is ready:

```
// on page load
$(document).ready(function(){

    // 10 images to div #image-board
    for(var i=0; i<10; i++){

        // create a div with image #i
        $('#image-board').append('<div><img src="my/collection/folder/Image'+i+'.jpg"></div>');
    }
});
```

don't forget to create in your HTML page a `<div id="image-board"></div>` where all images will be listed to

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to include lots of detail since you say you're unfamiliar with JavaScript. When you say stacked divs, I assume you mean one inside another. Start with a div with appropriate id and background  in your html `<div id="div0" style="background-image:url('map0.jpg')"></div>` Here's some Javascript using jQuery (a very common javascript library you can include with a script tag) that will add a new div inside your first div with the updated url name.

```
    for (var i = 0; i < number_of_images - 1; i++) {
        var oldId = '#div' + i;
        var newId = 'div' + (i + 1);
        var newUrl = 'map'+(i+1)+'.jpg';
        var newdiv = '<div id="' + newId + '" style="background-image:url('+newUrl+')></div>';
        $(oldId).append(newdiv);
    }
```

The for loop will go over every image, then a string is created in a series of concatenations that becomes your updated div. The '$' searches for the DOM element with that id, then adds the new div inside it. If by stacked you meant a new div underneath but not contained by the previous div, use `.insertAfter` instead of `.append`. Assuming your webpage can reach all of the images, this should work. Also notice I've 0 indexed this (the standard in Javascript) but your question referred to map1 as the first map. If you have already named these maps, you may need to re-index the for loop to 1.

Comment: Here is a [pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/2uyJGfff) to what I have.  I changed `number_of_images` to 3 for now. Does this script make a new div based on the number I specify? Do I need to make `#div1`, `#div2` and so on, or will the script just use `#div0` attributes for the new divs?

Comment: Yes, this script creates a new div on every loop. If you want all the divs to have the same css attributes, add a common class to them. Change '<div id="' + newId + '" class="images" style="background-image:url('+newUrl+')></div>'; and add the class to the original div in your html. Then use CSS to delcare what you want.

Comment: Ok. I have removed the divContainer and now have the other divs by themselves as well as changed the JS to `.insertAfter`. I've added a new `class="div0"` but it doesn't seem to be working. I have also re-indexed my image names to start with 0 to comply with the standards. **Here's a new [Pastebin Link](http://pastebin.com/PNpM6F5V)**. How does it look? edit: Where should I put the script?

Comment: The usage of insertAfter is a little different than append. It is `$(newdiv).insertAfter(oldId);` Check that is correct, otherwise it will just delete the old div. Add you script tags after you've created the div with id div0 but before the closing body tag.